# How do I identify individual characters in a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that returns 'true' if a inputted string has no numbers in it and 'false' if it has any numbers in it

ex:

> 'Ohio' = true , 'agent 007' = false

So far I've tried

```
numbers = '0123456789'
Lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
Uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def alphabet_only(a_string):
    if a_string[:] not in numbers:
        print('true')
    else:
        print('false')
```

the problem is that i cant figure out how to identify a single number character by itself in a string to label it as false.

so far it will return

> 6 = false (good)
>
> 54 = true (bad)
>
> pie = true (good)
>
> pie18 = true (bad)

Answer (score 8):

Use isalpha() from the standard library

```
>>> test='test1'
>>> test.isalpha()
>>> False
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using regular expressions for this?

```
import re

def has_no_numbers(string):
    return re.search('[0-9]', string) is None
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to test if a string contains numbers, you have varied options

1. Use Regular expressions
2. Use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) `set(string.digits).intersection(st)) < 9`
3. Use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate). `len(st.translate(None, string.digits)) < len(st)`

But all of the above is an overkill because you just need to ensure that one of the characters is a digit. It does not matter which digit or the number of occurrence. In such a case using str.isdigit check and using `any` short circuit boolean evaluation should be the right approach.

```
>>> def has_numbers(st):
    return any(e.isdigit() for e in st)

>>> has_numbers('agent 007')
True
>>> has_numbers('agent')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

With set-intersection:

```
digits = set("0123456789")

def alphabet_only(a_string):
   if set(a_string) & digits:
       print ("false")
   else:
       print ("true")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do as follows:

```
import string

def alphabet_only(a_string):
    if all(v not in string.digits for v in a_string):
        print('true')
    else:
        print('false')


alphabet_only("6") # false        
alphabet_only("54") # false  
alphabet_only("pie") # true       
alphabet_only("pie18") #  false 
alphabet_only("Ohio")  # true       
alphabet_only("agent 007") # false
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a simpler way  than the prevoiusly proposed:

if you do this:

```
list(string123)
```

you'll get something like this

```
['s','t','r','i','n','g','1','2','3']
```

Now all you need to do is set up a simple for loop to check each entry (not tested):

```
some_list = list(string123)
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    if some_list[i] == 1 or some_list[i] == 2 or ..... or some_list[i] == 9:
        print 'False'
    else:
        print 'True'
```

or as pointed out by another user the if condition can be changed for the following:

```
0 <= some_list[i] <= 9:
```

And thus make the code more compact.

Here's a more *beautiful* version of the code:

```
for c in 'string123':
    0 <= c <= 9:
        print 'False'
    else:
        print 'True'
```

Comment: or just `if 0 <= some_list[i] <= 9`; no need to enumerate all the different possibilities

Comment: Of course, I was just following the zen of python: explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: "Beautiful is better than ugly"

Comment: `for i in range(len(some_list)):` is always ugly. Better is `for c in 'string'`:.